# Can someone help me align the X on this div? I have been playing with it forever and cannot figure it out :(

Tags: html, css, block

This is the pen

https://codepen.io/brxtn/pen/rNOJKBq

```
<div class="annotation">
<div class="annotext">
<div class=annobar></div>
<div class="x">✕</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
</div>
```

```
.annotation{
  height:auto;
  font-family:cardo;
  width:280px;
  text-align:justify;
  font-size:0.9em;
  padding:30px;
  transition:all 0.4s linear;
}

.annotext{
width:250px;  
  padding:0px;
}

.x{
  padding-left:3px;
  padding-top:3px;
  color:#c73626;
}


.annobar{
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;       
    border-top:1px solid #c73626;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

And I have been struggling to keep everything inside the "annotation" div and get this alignment of the "annobar" with the text:

[image: How can I align the X with the text and sit beside the bar?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position the x absolutely using the half the margin of the annobar as the top position (so -0.5rem in this case) and making the annotext `position: relative` (so the top-right corner is where you want the x):

```css
.annotation{
  height:auto;
  font-family:cardo;
  width:280px;
  text-align:justify;
  font-size:0.9em;
  padding:30px;
  transition:all 0.4s linear;
}

.annotext{
  width:250px;  
  padding:0px;
  position: relative;
}

.x{
  padding-left:3px;
  padding-top:3px;
  color:#c73626;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -0.5rem;
}


.annobar{
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;       
    border-top:1px solid #c73626;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="annotation"><div class="annotext"><div class=annobar><div class="x">✕</div></div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div></div>
```

Comment: position:absolute is not a responsive solution, and neither is my solution for that matter. rather than specifying width:px it would be more beneficial to a responsive design to use percentages on the width. This means that when the browser is resized and div is contained within other parent elements, the width of the div will grow/shrink as needed, all while maintaining the position of the header div I created in my response to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I added a header div, and then put both the X and the red line inside of it. Then I used float left on both of those. I then set the width of the main parent to restrict the width of the text. You'll have to clear:both on the text div because of the floats.

**EDIT**
Corrected Codepen Link
**[Here](https://codepen.io/josgall/pen/ZEbrRRZ) is the codepen.**

**Use this for the HTML**

```
<div class="annotation">
  <div class="annotext">
    <div class="header-div">
      <div class=annobar></div>
      <div class="x">✕</div>
    <div/>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Use this for the CSS**

```
.annotation{
  height:auto;
  font-family:cardo;
  width:265px;
  text-align:justify;
  font-size:0.9em;
  padding:30px;
  transition:all 0.4s linear;
}

.annotext{  
  padding:0px;
}

.x{
  padding-left:3px;
  padding-top:3px;
  color:#c73626;
  float:left;
}


.annobar{
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;       
    border-top:1px solid #c73626;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
    float: left;
    width:250px;
}
.text{
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
float: right
```

to the css for x. This will make the X appear on the right.

Additionally, if you move the X to be inside annotext, and make annotext "float: left", the X appears on top of the line.

To finish it off, you make the X have a white background to cover up the line.

Here is the end result:

```css
.annotation{
  height:auto;
  font-family:cardo;
  width:280px;
  text-align:justify;
  font-size:0.9em;
  padding:30px;
  transition:all 0.4s linear;
}

.annotext{
width:250px;  
  padding:0px;
  float:left;
}

.x{
   padding-left:3px;
  padding-top:3px;
  color:#c73626;
  float:right;
  background-color:white;
}


.annobar{
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;    
    border-top:1px solid #c73626;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="annotation">
  
  <div class="annotext">
    <div class="x">✕</div>
    <div class=annobar></div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have tried all kinds of things with the float property but have had no success :( When I do this, I get the x beside the text rather than beside the bar, and when I try to put the x inside of the annobar div, it appears beneath the bar rather than beside it D:

Comment: Perhaps try doing a float and make sure the text has a `clear:both` property so it goes on the next line. Otherwise, try a grid layout with 2 columns that will place the x on that area. Make the text take up the whole row